# I'm having trouble putting who wins in my game

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, visual-c++

So everything in my code works so far, but I don't know why the checkWinner function doesn't work. In my `Bool checkWinner` function,  I used bool. When I call the function I'm not sure where to put it as well.

**What I tried**: one place where I have tried was in my for loop in the main function. Ex:

```
checkWinner(board, gwinner)
```

However it doesn't work, the game keeps on playing when someone even has three X's or O's.

**Possible problems I see:** I'm not sure what's wrong, could it be my `checkwinner` function, or could it be my `playerChoice` function?

The question is why isn't a winner being picked? Thank you for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 3; // For the rows
const int COLS = 3; // For the number of columns;
void showBoard(const char[][COLS], int); // Shows the board
void playerChoice(char[][COLS], char); // shows the player choice
bool checkwinner(const char[][COLS], string);

int main()
{
    char board[ROWS][COLS] = { { '*', '*', '*' }, { '*', '*', '*' }, { '*', '*', '*' } };
    string gwinner = " ";
    showBoard(board, 3); // displays the board

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        playerChoice(board, 'X');
        showBoard(board, 3);

        playerChoice(board, 'O');
        showBoard(board, 3);
    }

    cout << "The winner is: " << gwinner;
}

void showBoard(const char arr[][COLS], int SIZE)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
            cout << '|' << arr[row][col];
        cout << '|' << endl;
    }
}

void playerChoice(char arr[][COLS], char name)
{
    int row, columns;
    char board[ROWS][COLS] = { { '*', '*', '*' }, { '*', '*', '*' }, { '*', '*', '*' } };

    cout << "What row would you like?\n";
    cout << "Row: ";
    cin >> row;

    while (row < 1 || row > 3) {
        cout << "Error please pick a row between 1 and 3.\n";
        cout << "Row: ";
        cin >> row;
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "What column would you like?\n";
    cout << "Column: ";
    cin >> columns;

    while (columns < 1 || columns > 3) {
        cout << "Error,please pick a column between 1 and 3.\n";
        cout << "Column: ";
        cin >> columns;
        cout << endl;
    }

    if (arr[row - 1][columns - 1] == '*') {
        arr[row - 1][columns - 1] = name;
    }
    else {
        cout << "This space is occupied.\n";
        cout << "Please select again\n";
    }
}

bool checkwinner(const char arr[][COLS], string gwinner)
{
    bool winner = false;

    if ((arr[0][0] == arr[0][1]) && (arr[0][1] == arr[0][2])) // checks row
    {
        winner = true;
    }
    else if ((arr[1][0] == arr[1][1]) && (arr[1][1] == arr[1][2])) // checks row
    {
        winner = true;
    }
    else if ((arr[2][0] == arr[2][1]) && (arr[2][1] == arr[2][2])) // checks row
    {
        winner = true;
    }
    else if ((arr[0][0] == arr[1][0]) && (arr[1][0] == arr[2][0])) // checks columns
    {
        winner = true;
    }
    else if ((arr[0][1] == arr[1][1]) && (arr[1][1] == arr[2][1])) // checks columns
    {
        winner = true;
    }
    else if ((arr[0][2] == arr[1][2]) && (arr[1][2] == arr[2][2])) // checks columns
    {
        winner = true;
    }
    else if ((arr[0][0] == arr[1][1]) && (arr[1][1] == arr[2][2])) // checks diagonal
    {
        winner = true;
    }
    else if ((arr[2][0] == arr[1][1]) && (arr[1][1] == arr[0][2])) // checks diagonal
    {
        winner = true;
    }
    else {
        gwinner = "It's a tie! ";
        winner = false;
    }

    return winner; // returns the winner
}
```

Comment: Odds are good that your development tools came with a debugger. With a debugger you can run the program at your speed and watch what the computer does with your code as the computer does it. Typical usage is to advance to where you believe the problem is with a breakpoint and then step through the code line-by-line with an eye out for the unexpected, usually the wrong branch taken at a decision or the wrong value stored in a variable. The unexpected means either you or your program is wrong, and either one needs to be fixed.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `checkwinner()` anywhere.

Comment: MARRSVISTER, Tip: use your tool editor to auto format the code.  Easier for you and us to review the code.

Comment: Hmmm, Try `const int COLS = 3;` --> `#define COLS 3`.  I am rusty on the correctness of `const int COLS = 3; void showBoard(const char[][COLS], int);`

Comment: Since this is tagged with `visual-c++` you have the microsoft debugger built into your IDE. Go to the line `bool winner = false;` and press `F9`  then you can run your code in the debugger by pressing `F5` and see that your `checkwinner(const char arr[][COLS], string gwinner)` function was never called.

Comment: You could simplify your program with `for` loops.  For each row, if `arr[row][0] == arr[row][1] ...`.

Comment: Your function `checkwinner` is modifying the `gwinner` parameter, so you'll need to pass the `gwinner` by reference.  Otherwise you are modifying **a copy** of the caller's variable.